# Unable to open dependencies file Xcode 14

Tags: ios, xcode

I just upgraded my Mac to Ventura and now I am getting this build error:

> unable to open dependencies file (/Users/dsynkd/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Vitruvian-gexnrbahgvfqgbaswepnavszwmdj/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Vitruvian.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Vitruvian.build/Objects-normal-asan/arm64/NutritionixItemSearchResponseModel.d)

I tried cleaning build folder and DerivedData. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out one of the files had an error in it, but for some reason this obscure error was being shown instead of the actual error. Seems to be a bug with XCode or SwiftUI...